# Group by in SQL Server with one value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data and trying to group by the, but not getting the data as I want .

```
create table #test 
( 
     id int, 
     value int, 
     code int, 
     info varchar(20)  
)

insert into #test
values (1234, 7666, 1, '1stfail'),
       (1234, 7665, 2, '2ndfail'),
       (1234, 7664, 3, '3rdfail'),
       (2434, 8777, 1, '1stfail')

select id, value, code, min(info)  
from #test
```

I am getting result as below

[image]

I want result like this

[image]

Comment: You should get an error with that code... since you have no `GROUP BY`. Aside from that, the data is the same minus the fact that you omitted some values in an attempt to make a report look. Let your application layer do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `CASE` and only output the ID when `row_number()` equals 1.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                 ORDER BY code) = 1 THEN
           id
       END id,
       value,
       code,
       info 
       FROM #test;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c4eac2b279af3f7c9aacb4be18687f40)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use LAG in order to achive this. LAG advances to next row to get value of column.

```
select 
  case when idNew = id then null else id end idCol, 
  value, code, info 
from (
   SELECT id, LAG(id) OVER(Order by id) idNew, code, value, info from #test
) as t
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition that compares the id with the maximum of each group:

```
select 
  case 
    when value = (select max(value) from #test where id = t.id) then t.id
    else null
  end as id,
  value, 
  code,
  info
from #test as t
order by t.id, t.value desc, t.code
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4abc233d087286f81908614be0e88baf)